# Upload some images to website

Tags: web, popup

I need something like a window browse popup to select some images to upload to my website, how can i do that?

I already googled sometimes but found no answer to this one.

Comment: In case of asp.net use **FileUpload** control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<input type="file" multiple />` or [Jquery](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)